# Find all four roots of quartic equation $x^4-x+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quartics

How to solve

$$x^4-x+1=0$$

My attempt:

$$x^4-x+1=0$$

$$\implies x^4-x^3-x+1+x^3=0$$

$$\implies x^3(x-1)-(x-1)+x^3=0$$

$$\implies (x^3-1)(x-1)+x^3=0$$

But, I couldn't find a way to combine $x^3$ into that factorization.

I then looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution) to see how to solve a quartic. I'm not sure which method is the best one. The coefficients are pretty simple (in the form $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, $a=e=1$, $b=c=0$, $d=-1$). Should I just use the [general formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for quartic equations, or something else?

Also, I couldn't find a post on here talking about how to solve quartic equations. If someone finds a link to such a post then I might as well just delete this question.
The only post I found that might be useful is this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658305/a-different-kind-of-depressed-quartic) but sadly there are no answers there.

EDIT: I would prefer all four solutions, real or complex.

Comment: Is $x\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @callculus check my edit.

Comment: Looks like $-1<x<1$

Comment: @Lee How did you get that inequality? Is there some kind of rule that allows you to say that?

Comment: In general a polynomial equationl with degree 4 cannot solved algebraically.

Comment: @callculus, that is incorrect. There is a quartic formula, though it is somewhat unwieldy.

Comment: @Integrand Do you have a link?

Comment: @AidenChow if we work with real numbers, than if you insert $x>1$ then definitely the equality doesnt hold, same for $x<-1$

Comment: @callculis Look at Ferrari Formula.

Comment: @EDX Should I use that formula to solve this question or the general formula?

Comment: @callculus I provided a link to the general formula for quartic equations in my question.

Comment: @Aiden Chow Yes

Comment: Mathematica gives the approximate solutions $-0.727\pm 0.934i$ and $0.727\pm 0.430 i$. I figured you were looking for exact solutions but this gives a place to start.

Comment: Where is this from? Do you have reason to believe that the solutions can be found via a neat method (i.e. without the monstrous general method for solving quartic polynomials)?

Comment: @Qwertiops I don't really have any reason to believe that this question would give neat answers. I just wanted to see what the best method for solving this would be and then maybe solve it myself. It seems like there isn't any neat method to do this problem based on the answers and comments.

Answer (score 9):

There are no real solutions because $x^4-x+1$ attains a positive minimum at $x=1/\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Answer (score 8):

Note that $x^4-x+1=0$ is a deeply-depressed quartic equation, which makes it manageable. In fact, it can be factorized as

$$x^4-x+1= \left( x^2- ax+ \frac{a^3-1}{2a} \right)  \left( x^2+ ax+ \frac{a^3+1}{2a} \right) =0\tag1
$$

where $a$ satisfies the cubic equation $(a^2)^3-4a^2-1=0$ and can be obtained analytically
$$a = \sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt3} \cos\left( \frac13\cos^{-1}\frac{3\sqrt3}{16}\right)}$$

Then, solve the two quadratic equations in (1) to obtain the four complex roots

$$x = \frac a2 \pm \frac i2\sqrt{a^2-\frac2a},\>\>\>
-\frac a2 \pm \frac i2\sqrt{a^2+\frac2a}
$$

Answer (score 5):

A new method for solving quartics known as the ferrari method which has quite posts on this site
so we add a factor of $(ex+f)^2$ on both sides so the equation becomes 
$$(x^2+ax+b)^2=(ex+f)^2$$
and we have to determine $a,b,e,f$

> so expand $(x^2+ax+b)^2$ and you will get
>   $$x^4+a^2x^2+b^2+2bx^2+2ax^3+2abx=x^4-x+1+e^2x^2+f^2+2efx$$
>   on comparing coefficients we get $$\begin{align} a =0 \rightarrow (1)
> & \\2ef = 1 \ \ \  \rightarrow (2) \\1+f^2=b^2\rightarrow (3) \\e^2 = 2b\rightarrow (4) \end{align}$$
>   now square the $2^{nd}$ equation to get $$f^2 = \frac{1}{8b}$$
>   put this result in $(3)$ and form a cubic polynomial in $b$
>   which is 
>   $$8b^3-1-8b=0$$
>   after this I think you can proceed

Answer (score 4):

It's sufficent to show that it has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$:
Let $f(x)=x^4-x+1$, then $f'(x)=4x^3-1$, $x_0=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{4}}$,
$f(x)$ decreases on $(-\infty,x_0)$ and increases on $(x_0,\infty)$ so it's sufficent to find $f(x_0)$.
$$f(x_0)=\frac{1}{8}\left(8-3\sqrt[3]{2}\right)>0\hbox{ as }
8^3>3^3\cdot 2$$
For complex roots one can try [Ferrari method. Encyclopedia of Mathematics.](http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Ferrari_method&oldid=35675)

Answer (score 3):

Before diving into any details, I consulted Wolfram Alpha and noted that the roots are non-real complex conjugate pairs. [Results from Wolfram Alpha for $x^4-x=1=0$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbdiw.png)

From the section on the [nature of solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution), I cite:
`The possible cases for the nature of the roots are as follows: [...] If $P > 0$ or $D > 0$ then there are two pairs of non-real complex conjugate roots. [...]`

We calculate some of the related coefficients. We find that $$P=8ac-3b^2=0$$ and $$R=b^3+8da^2-4abc=-8<0$$ and $$D=64a^3e-16a^2c^2+16ab^2c-16a^bd-3b^4=64>0$$ and  $\Delta_0=12>0$.

The case $P=0$ and $D>0$ does not seem to be listed. But actually, I should have started with the discriminant $\Delta$ (which has only two non-zero terms, subject to human error) and I calculate that $\Delta=229>0$.

Whenever $\Delta>0$, all four roots are real or none of them are. I do not see a reason why $P=0$ is not listed.

Answer (score 3):

The Newton-Raphson method uses an iterative process to approach one root of a any function:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
This could be a method to see that the equation $$x^4-x+1=0$$ not have any real solutions.

Indeed if you separated the fourth degree equation into two functions, the first $f(x)=x^4$ and the second $g(x)=x-1$, starting from the equation $x^4-x+1=0$, using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) to draw one function, for example, you can observe that there is no intersections beetween $f$ and $g$. I have chosen the graphic way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Equation $\displaystyle p x + x^4 = t$

Solution:

$\displaystyle Q = ((-(27 p^4 + 128 t^3) + 3 (3 p^4 (27 p^4 + 256 t^3))^{1/2})/2)^{1/3}$

$\displaystyle A = (Q + 4 t (4 t/Q - 1))/(6 p)$

$\displaystyle B = (32 (3 p A + t))^{-1/6}$

$\displaystyle F = 256 B^{12} t (16 A^4 + 2 A p - t)$

$\displaystyle R_2 = cos((arccos(1 + 8 F) + 2 \pi j)/4)$

$\displaystyle j=0,1,2,3$

$\displaystyle R = 4 B^3 (1 - A^2)$

$\displaystyle y = (R_2 - R)/(4 B^4)$

$\displaystyle x= A \pm (1 + B y)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial is irreducible but solvable.

$$x≈-0.72714 \pm 0.93410 i\qquad \land\qquad x≈0.72714 \pm 0.43001 i$$